# Opening context menu just above item in win 8 metro app

Tags: windows-8

I have a list of items defined in a ListView. When user click or tap any item, I want to show a PopupMenu just above the selected Item. How should I position the PopupMenu?

```
varmenu =newPopupMenu();
menu.Commands.Add(
newUICommand("Remove", (x) =>
{...
// Create the message dialog and set its content
}, 1));

var chosenCommand     =awaitmenu.ShowForSelectionAsync(GetElementRect((FrameworkElement)sender));

Rect GetElementRect(FrameworkElement element)
{    
    GeneralTransform buttonTransform = element.TransformToVisual(null);
    Pointpoint = buttonTransform.TransformPoint(newPoint());
    returnnewRect(point,newSize(element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the code I've been using to open up a popup menu above a button in an app bar.

```
private async void OnOpenMenu(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var transform = button.TransformToVisual(this);
    var point = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

    var menu = new PopupMenu();

    menu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Menu Item 1"));
    menu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Menu Item 2"));

    await menu.ShowAsync(point);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this but now we are trying hold to select an item and then instead of showing a menu placing enabling delete button. And this is much better then showing a menu with only one option :)

Comment: @Nigel I want to display context below textblock...but using above code menu is displayed above textblock. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You can tweak the numbers in the transformed point from 0, 0. This shifts the position of the menu.